# getting text from table-element with an included link

Tags: javascript, dom, iframe

is there an easy cross-browser way to extract the text from a table-element? I tried

```
if ( myTable.getElementsByTagName("TR")[j].getElementsByTagName("TD")[1] != null) {
            Desc = myTable.getElementsByTagName("TR")   [j].getElementsByTagName("TD")[1].innerHTML || "";
```

The element I accesses looked like

TD CLASS="DESC_TEXT" WIDTH=95%>Procedure voor Uniface tbv aanroep is_death_date_consistent.
 /TD>

and I got:

```
Procedure voor Uniface tbv aanroep <A HREF=#is_death_date_consistent>is_death_date_consistent</A>
```

where I would like to have Procedure voor Uniface tbv aanroep is_death_date_consistent, so without the link. Any suggestions? Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) instead of innerHTML.

IE8 doesn't support textContent. If you need to support IE8 or earlier, you can use innerText.

```
var td = [j].getElementsByTagName("TD")[1];
return td.textContent || td.innerText || "";
```

Comment: I already tried innerText instead of innerHTML and got nothing at all!

Comment: Updated answer. Try textContent.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for your quick response, after some juggling it works :))

Comment: Great! Don't forget to click the up arrow and the check mark next to the answer. :)

Comment: another not-understandable thing. I've been creating 4 iframes, setting the src-propertie and an onload-event After setting these I wanted to read their contents, put all stuff to an array and sort them. Finally I want to read that array to put all elements to a table in my HTML-doc. The funny part is, I have to put an alert-message before sorting the array, leaving this will keep that array empty!!?? With "Developmenttools" for IE8 I found out that the onload-event was triggered just before the script was finished! At that time I already removed the iframes :)) I don't understand why??

Comment: I'd have to see the code. You should ask another question, but read this first. :) http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks for you help, found the answer to the delay. My mistake, forgot that my pushbutton event was still executing before the onload events could be handled. Now its working fine, except in Chrome where I have some domain problem :(( Will google for an answer as I think it's same domain as it's loading from same disc-location. Tx anyway